# Retrieving Facebook friends works inconsistently on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-friends

I am using the following code to login a user and fetch his facebook friends :

```
 FBSDKLoginButton* loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.delegate = self;
    loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```

Problem:
The Facebook friends list is not getting retrieved for some of the users. 
I have verified the Facebook app versions for these users - They are using the latest Facebook app version .

Answer (score 0):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, you can only get friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too. Btw, it does not matter which Facebook App version they have installed, that´s irrelevant.

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: All the users who could not receive the friends info had authorised my app with the user_friends permission.

Comment: But did _their_ friends also grant `user_friends` permission to your app? Otherwise your app can’t see them.

Comment: yes . All the friends of that users have granted the user_friends permission

Comment: in that case it´s impossible to help you with the information we have right now, i´m afraid.